# Conectar mysql desde una red local

Tags: mysql

me surge la siguiente duda, estoy creando una aplicación para una institución, la cual me pidió que sus datos se guardarán de manera local en una computadora que ellos poseen y desde allí se comunicaran esos datos en la red local, logrando así que todas sus computadoras trabajaran conectadas a los mismo datos, mi pregunta es, cómo logro que una base de datos de Mysql alojada en una computadora en particular se comunique de manera local con las otras computadoras que posee esta institución... gracias de antemano por sus ayuda... Dato importante no tengo la opción de subir la base de datos a un hosting de Mysql ya que su internet es de mala calidad.

Comment: Crear una red local asignar ips a cada host, conectar a la PC que almacene el gestor por medio de la IP

Answer (score 2):

Lo más importante acá es que exista comunicación entre todas ésas máquinas, es decir si están en el mismo segmento de red, no tendrías problemas al acceder a través de la dirección IP donde tendrías el servidor.

- En caso de que estén en redes diferentes podrías optar por crear una
  **VPN**.
- Otra solución es publicar la IP del server a través de internet
  (es decir abrir puertos en el **router**, hacer `nat`...) o incluso podrías
  utilizar algún servicio de dominios como **DynDNS** o **No-Ip**.

Todo va a depender de tu infraestructura de red y si es posible la comunicación IP a través de ellas

Comment: otra cosa para añadir: cuando instales el servidor de bbdd, recuerda que hay cierta configuracion que hace que solo sea visible en el equipo local (por defecto). Tendras que configurarlo para que el propio servidor permita la conexion desde otros puntos de la red.